# VBA Set Columns equal to each other if other column values match

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have two Excel worksheets. If the unique ID column of both spreadsheets matches, then I want to copy the value from column C in sheet 1 to column H in sheet 2. The unique ID column in sheet 1 is Q, sheet 2 it is F. The code below matches the IDs between the sheets and deletes the rows in Sheet 1 that do not have a match in Sheet 2. I was trying to modify the loop in this code to achieve what I need.

I believe the line after THEN in the loop is all that needs to be modified, and then I would delete the last section of code that deletes rows. I may be wrong.

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range
    Dim lnLastRow1 As Long, lnLastRow2 As Long
    Dim lnTopRow1 As Long, lnTopRow2 As Long
    Dim lnCols As Long, i As Long


    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    ' Duplicate Sheet 1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "RAW DATA"
    DoEvents
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    lnTopRow1 = 2 'first row containing data in ws1 
    lnTopRow2 = 2 'first row containing data in ws2 

     'Find last cells containing data:
    lnLastRow1 = ws1.Range("Q:Q").Find("*", Range("Q1"), LookIn:=xlValues, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lnLastRow2 = ws2.Range("F:F").Find("*", Range("F1"), LookIn:=xlValues, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Set rng = ws2.Range("F" & lnTopRow2 & ":F" & lnLastRow2)

    lnCols = ws1.Columns.Count
    ws1.Columns(lnCols).Clear 'Using the very right-hand column of the sheet

    For i = lnLastRow1 To lnTopRow1 Step -1
        For Each c In rng
            If ws1.Range("Q" & i).Value = c.Value Then
                ws1.Cells(i, lnCols).Value = "KEEP"  ' Add tag to right-hand column of sheet if match found
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    Next i

     ' Delete rows where the right-hand column of the sheet is blank
     Set rng = ws1.Range(Cells(lnTopRow1, lnCols), Cells(lnLastRow1, lnCols))
     rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
     ws1.Columns(lnCols).Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: Why isn't an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair good enough?

Comment: It could be, I'm just not familiar and others will be executing this often so it's typically easiest to teach them to run a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to replace the inner nested loop with VBA's application of the worksheet's [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca). If you build a non-contiguous range of the cells/rows to remove with the [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) while simultaneously transferring the values for rows that match you should be rewarded with an appreciable speed increase.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareXferDelete()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim delrng As Range
    Dim lnTopRow1 As Long, lnLastRow1 As Long
    Dim mrw As Variant, i As Long

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws1

        ' Duplicate Sheet 1
        .Copy After:=.Parent.Sheets(.Parent.Sheets.Count)
        .Parent.Sheets(.Parent.Sheets.Count).Name = "RAW DATA" & .Parent.Sheets.Count

        'first row containing data in ws1
        lnTopRow1 = 2
        'Find last cells containing data:
        lnLastRow1 = .Range("Q:Q").Find("*", .Range("Q1"), LookIn:=xlValues, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        'seed the rows to delete so it doesn't have to be checked each time it is unioned
        Set delrng = .Range("Q" & lnLastRow1 + 1)

        For i = lnLastRow1 To lnTopRow1 Step -1
            mrw = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "Q").Value2, ws2.Columns("F"), 0)
            If Not IsError(mrw) Then
                'exists in Sheet2 - transfer value from ws1.C to ws2.H
                ws2.Cells(mrw, "H") = .Cells(i, "C").Value2
            Else
                'does not exist in Sheet2 - add to delete list
                Set delrng = Union(delrng, .Cells(i, "Q"))
            End If
        Next i

        ' Delete the rows collected into the union
        delrng.EntireRow.Delete

        'reactivate Sheet1 (unnecessary for code operation; simplifies things for user)
        .Activate
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Jeeped, this preforms well. However, the same ID may appear more than once in sheet 2, while it will only appear once in sheet 1. The result of this code is that the value of column C in sheet 1 is only copied to Column H in sheet 2 for the first occurrence in Sheet 2. Is there a fix to this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to concatenate or delimit multiple responses into a single cell. That sounds like a new question that needs an expanded narrative and sample data together with expected results. Please don't make this a [Russian Doll Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the FOR loop thus:

```
    For i = lnLastRow1 To lnTopRow1 Step -1
    For Each c In rng
        If ws1.Range("Q" & i).Value = c.Value Then
           ' ws1.Cells(i, lnCols).Value = "KEEP"  ' Add tag to right-hand column of sheet if match found
Dim valueToCopy As String
valueToCopy = ws1.Range("C" & i).Value
           Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
           Range("H" & c.Row).Value = valueToCopy
           Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
Next i
```

This should now work. I prefer the other suggestion anyhow!

Comment: This is close! But I need the value from column C of the row to be copied, not the unique ID cell that is being checked by the loop. How can I modify this? Thanks!